# How to combine parent and child based on parent value using promise in angular?

Tags: angular, promise

I am getting a response using promise in angular using httpclient. But i need to fetch another table using parent table id and combine both using map or list or somewhat. Since i am new to this concept can anyone help me with solutions or suggestions.

Please find the code below which i am trying to get it, i am not sure whether it is the correct code too.

```
  this.parentDetails = this.apiService.getParentDetails().then(
      parents => this.parentsList = parents,
      error => this.errorMessage = <any> error).then(
      parentsList => this.childId = parentsList.childId,
  );
```

From here i don't know how to take over and get both models

Comment: is that worked for you ?

Answer (score 0):

```
async getData() {
  try {
    // let both start at the same time
    let parentDetails$ = this.apiService.getParentDetails();
    let yourSecondRequest$ = this.apiService.getParentDetails();

    // get the values 
    let parentDetails = await parentDetails$;
    let yourSecondRequest = await yourSecondRequest$;

    parentDetails.something = yourSecondRequest.something;
  } catch (e) {
    // error handling in case a html request fails
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For dependent request you can make use of async & await.

```
  async function() 
  {
    var parentrequest1 = await service.getParentDetails().toPromise();
    //do processing of received data
    var childrequest2 = await service.getChildDetatils().toPromise();
    //do processing
  }
```